# Alternative of SQL LEN() Function in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Is there anything similar to **SQL** `LEN()` Function in realm? How can I retrieve something like

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE LEN(CustomerName) = 10;
```

Using realm in swift, I tried

```
realm.objects(Customers.self).filter("LEN(CustomerName) == 3")
```

got this error

> Unable to parse function name 'LEN:' into supported selector (LEN:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm does not yet support filtering based on the length of a string property. If this is something you'd like to use, please file an enhancement request on [Realm Cocoa's GitHub page](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `@count` property,

```
realm.objects(Customers.self).filter("CustomerName.@count ==  3")
```

Check [this](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/#keypath-collection-queries) collection query properties.

Comment: Thank you @x4h1d for your answer. I tried but no luck --- *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid predicate', reason: 'Aggregate operations can only be used on key paths that include an array property'.

Comment: You can check the link to find out a way.

Comment: Thank you. I'm checking the link :D